# spring-boot-starter-actuator is in conflict with hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I use spring-boot 1.4.3.RELEASE with Netflix Hystrix and I would provide Hystrix metrics via JMX. Hystrix is included in project by this snippet

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

For metrics via JMX I use hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher 1.5.9

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
  <artifactId>hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.9</version>
</dependency>
```

hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher is easy to use. It's enough to provide a static block with one single line
`HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerMetricsPublisher(HystrixServoMetricsPublisher.getInstance());`
as shown here

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  static {
    HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerMetricsPublisher(HystrixServoMetricsPublisher.getInstance());
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ExampleApplication.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

It works beautifully.

But we also need in our project Spring Boot Actuator. After adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

the hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher doesn't work anymore. The package `com.netlix.servo` is not available at JMX MBeans/attributes.

Here is a **small** sample project with the disabled spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency:
[hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher-jmx-example](https://github.com/hystrixFan/hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher-jmx-example)

If the dependency is enabled hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: 
I noticed that you are using Spring Boot 1.4.3 in your example project and that you're project setup is not correct. Things are different for Spring Boot 2.0.x, see below.

**Problems with your example project setup**

You are using `hystrix-servo-metrics-publisher` version `1.5.9`. This version is is incompatible with the Hystrix version `1.5.3` used by Spring Cloud `Brixton.SR5`. You can observe the incompatibility by starting your app, call `http://localhost:8080/remotecall` (to create initial Hystrix metrics) and then `http://localhost:8080/metrics` (to access the actuator endpoint). You then get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixThreadPoolProperties.maximumSize()Lcom/netflix/hystrix/strategy/properties/HystrixProperty;`. Setting the version to `1.5.3` resolves this issue.

**Solution for Spring Boot 1.x**

The reason that JMX metrics are not visible anymore with Actuator is caused by `ServoMetricsAutoConfiguration`, which is activated if Spring Boot Actuator is used. Here, a monitor registry bean is exposed, whose configuration depends on a `SpringMetricsConfigBean`. The new default registry class is `BasicMonitorRegistry`.

To get the original default JMX monitor registry back, add a `resources/application.properties` with the line `netflix.metrics.servo.registryClass=com.netflix.servo.jmx.JmxMonitorRegistry`.
This way metrics are exposed via both, JMX and the Spring Actuator metrics endpoint.

**Solution for Spring Boot 2.0.x**

For Spring Boot 2 the problem is different. I tracked the problem down to `io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.hystrix.HystrixMetricsBinder` (`micrometer` is a dependency of `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure`). Here, any existing publisher is replaced by a `MicrometerMetricsPublisher` when the `MetricsAutoConfiguration` class is triggered. Consequently, the statement `HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerMetricsPublisher(HystrixServoMetricsPublisher.getInstance());` does not have the desired effect. The publisher is simply discarded...

The problem with Hystrix plugins is that there can be only one plugin registered at a time per plugin type. Therefore, a solution is to replace an existing plugin with a "meta"-plugin that delegates to multiple plugin instances. This approach is also used in [`HystrixSecurityAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/hystrix/HystrixAutoConfiguration.java). With the config class below I managed to get Hystrix metrics exposed via both, JMX and Spring Boot Actuator (e.g. /actuator/metrics/hystrix.execution):

```
import com.netflix.hystrix.*;
import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.servopublisher.HystrixServoMetricsPublisher;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.HystrixPlugins;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixConcurrencyStrategy;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.eventnotifier.HystrixEventNotifier;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.executionhook.HystrixCommandExecutionHook;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.metrics.HystrixMetricsPublisher;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.metrics.HystrixMetricsPublisherCollapser;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.metrics.HystrixMetricsPublisherCommand;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.metrics.HystrixMetricsPublisherThreadPool;
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.properties.HystrixPropertiesStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({Hystrix.class, HystrixServoMetricsPublisher.class})
@AutoConfigureAfter(MetricsAutoConfiguration.class)
public class HystrixServoAndMicrometerConfig {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Keeps references of existing Hystrix plugins
        HystrixMetricsPublisher existingMetricsPublisher = HystrixPlugins.getInstance().getMetricsPublisher();
        HystrixConcurrencyStrategy concurrencyStrategy = HystrixPlugins.getInstance().getConcurrencyStrategy();
        HystrixEventNotifier eventNotifier = HystrixPlugins.getInstance().getEventNotifier();
        HystrixPropertiesStrategy propertiesStrategy = HystrixPlugins.getInstance().getPropertiesStrategy();
        HystrixCommandExecutionHook commandExecutionHook = HystrixPlugins.getInstance().getCommandExecutionHook();

        if (existingMetricsPublisher != null) {
            HystrixPlugins.reset();
            // Registers existing plugins except the new ServoAndExistingMetricsPublisher plugin
            HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerMetricsPublisher(new ServoAndExistingMetricsPublisher(
                    existingMetricsPublisher, HystrixServoMetricsPublisher.getInstance()));
            HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerConcurrencyStrategy(concurrencyStrategy);
            HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerEventNotifier(eventNotifier);
            HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerPropertiesStrategy(propertiesStrategy);
            HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerCommandExecutionHook(commandExecutionHook);
        } else {
            HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerMetricsPublisher(HystrixServoMetricsPublisher.getInstance());
        }
    }

    private static class ServoAndExistingMetricsPublisher extends HystrixMetricsPublisher {

        private static class ServoAndOtherMetricsPublisherCommand implements HystrixMetricsPublisherCommand {
            private final HystrixMetricsPublisherCommand servoMetricsPublisherCommand;
            private final HystrixMetricsPublisherCommand existingMetricsPublisherCommand;

            ServoAndOtherMetricsPublisherCommand(HystrixMetricsPublisherCommand servoMetricsPublisherCommand,
                                                 HystrixMetricsPublisherCommand existingMetricsPublisherCommand) {
                this.servoMetricsPublisherCommand = servoMetricsPublisherCommand;
                this.existingMetricsPublisherCommand = existingMetricsPublisherCommand;
            }

            @Override
            public void initialize() {
                servoMetricsPublisherCommand.initialize();
                existingMetricsPublisherCommand.initialize();
            }
        }

        private final HystrixMetricsPublisher existingMetricsPublisher;
        private final HystrixMetricsPublisher servoMetricsPublisher;

        ServoAndExistingMetricsPublisher(HystrixMetricsPublisher existingMetricsPublisher,
                                         HystrixMetricsPublisher servoMetricsPublisher) {
            this.existingMetricsPublisher = existingMetricsPublisher;
            this.servoMetricsPublisher = servoMetricsPublisher;
        }

        @Override
        public HystrixMetricsPublisherCommand getMetricsPublisherForCommand(HystrixCommandKey commandKey, HystrixCommandGroupKey commandGroupKey, HystrixCommandMetrics metrics, HystrixCircuitBreaker circuitBreaker, HystrixCommandProperties properties) {
            HystrixMetricsPublisherCommand servoMetricsPublisherCommand = servoMetricsPublisher.getMetricsPublisherForCommand(commandKey, commandGroupKey, metrics, circuitBreaker, properties);
            HystrixMetricsPublisherCommand existingMetricsPublisherCommand = existingMetricsPublisher.getMetricsPublisherForCommand(commandKey, commandGroupKey, metrics, circuitBreaker, properties);
            return new ServoAndOtherMetricsPublisherCommand(servoMetricsPublisherCommand, existingMetricsPublisherCommand);
        }

        @Override
        public HystrixMetricsPublisherThreadPool getMetricsPublisherForThreadPool(HystrixThreadPoolKey threadPoolKey, HystrixThreadPoolMetrics metrics, HystrixThreadPoolProperties properties) {
            return servoMetricsPublisher.getMetricsPublisherForThreadPool(threadPoolKey, metrics, properties);
        }

        @Override
        public HystrixMetricsPublisherCollapser getMetricsPublisherForCollapser(HystrixCollapserKey collapserKey, HystrixCollapserMetrics metrics, HystrixCollapserProperties properties) {
            return servoMetricsPublisher.getMetricsPublisherForCollapser(collapserKey, metrics, properties);
        }
    }
}
```